# SignalR disconnect issue in version 1.1.2

Tags: signalr

I am using signalr 1.1.2 version. Signalr server is hosted as asp.netweb API (REST service). 
SignalR client is javascript.

I am facing an issue related to reconnecting signalr clients. Everytime I recycle the application pool of the REST service or change web.config file of Rest service , my signalr client closes the current websocket, tries to reconnect, it does get reconnected but then after a while i get the message on client

"Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout (100000ms), "

I have configred the disconnecttimeout on server to be 100 seconds.
GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = 100;

Here is the client log:

[10:39:21 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket closed jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:39:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:39:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets reconnecting jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:39:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://dev.fmdc.com:6756/Push/signalr/reconnect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=-yPgnSfqKCkoHAHtgqoSY8RA4dmu4sZDZS545DEFUfXGJP-4J0fmp3Tw9NlEWpQSdOoWtsm70t1wikpZCvgmD4YzD1dwS-UNFUDXV-2Q954Qh6TZ0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notifierhub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C4%7CR%2C1%7CS%2C0%7CT%2C0&u=1048635&a=1094328&tid=0' jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:39:26 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:39:26 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets reconnecting jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10
[10:39:26 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://dev.fmdc.com:6756/Push/signalr/reconnect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=-yPgnSfqKCkoHAHtgqoSY8RA4dmu4sZDZS545DEFUfXGJP-4J0fmp3Tw9NlEWpQSdOoWtsm70t1wikpZCvgmD4YzD1dwS-UNFUDXV-2Q954Qh6TZ0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notifierhub%22%7D%5D&messageId=B%2C4%7CR%2C1%7CS%2C0%7CT%2C0&u=1048635&a=1094328&tid=5' jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:39:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:39:54 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'rejoined' on hub 'NotifierHub'. jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

[10:41:03 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout (100000ms), disconnecting. jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10
[10:41:03 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10
[10:41:03 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: Closing the Websocket jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js?v=20130903071956:10

This issue was not happening with previous version of SignalR.(i.e. 1.0.0 rc1)

Comment: Do you see the issue on any browser? Could you share a minimum repro on a zip file or git repository?